# JNI on Android: Callback from native with Integer parameter works, with String or Void it doesn't. Why?

Tags: android, c++, kotlin, callback, java-native-interface

I have a callback class for doing callbacks from native C++ code to Kotlin (not sure if Kotlin/Java makes a difference here, if so, is there any documentation on that?).
I have a working callback with an integer parameter, that I call from different native threads without a problem. Now I want to add a second one that sends a String, but for some reason that doesn't work.

My callback class implementation looks like this:

```
 jclass target;
 jmethodID id;

 Callback::Callback(JavaVM &jvm, jobject object) : g_jvm(jvm), g_object(object) {
     JNIEnv *g_env;
     int getEnvStat = g_jvm.GetEnv((void **) &g_env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

     if (g_env != NULL) {
         target = g_env->GetObjectClass(g_object);
         id = g_env->GetMethodID(target, "integerCallback", "(I)V");
     }
 }

 void Callback::call(int integerValue, const char *stringValue) {
     JNIEnv *g_env;
     int getEnvStat = g_jvm.GetEnv((void **) &g_env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

     if (getEnvStat == JNI_EDETACHED) {
         if (g_jvm.AttachCurrentThread(&g_env, NULL) != 0) {
             LOGD("GetEnv: Failed to attach");
         }
     } else if (getEnvStat == JNI_OK) {
        LOGD("GetEnv: JNI_OK");
     } else if (getEnvStat == JNI_EVERSION) {
        LOGD("GetEnv: version not supported");
     }

     g_env->CallVoidMethod(g_object, id, (jint) integerValue);
 }
```

It gets instantiated in my `native-lib.cpp`like this:

```
extern "C" {


std::unique_ptr<Callback> callback;

JavaVM *g_jvm = nullptr;

static jobject myJNIClass;


jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *pJvm, void *reserved) {
    g_jvm = pJvm;
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_my_app_common_jni_JniBridge_loadNative(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
                                                          jstring URI, jboolean isWaitMode) {
    myJNIClass = env->NewGlobalRef(instance);

    if (callback == nullptr) {
        callback = std::make_unique<Callback>(*g_jvm, myJNIClass);
    }

}
```

The callback method it talks to is in my `JniBridge.kt` (the threading part is probbaly irrelevant to the problem):

```
object JniBridge {
    init {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib")
        Timber.d("Native Lib loaded!")
    }

    fun load(fileName: String, isWaitMode: Boolean) {
        loadNative(fileName, isWaitMode)
    }

    fun integerCallback(value: Int) {
        someListener?.invoke(value)
    }

    private external fun loadNative(fileName: String, isWaitMode: Boolean)
}
```

So now if my native code triggers the `call()` method in my callback, my `integerCallback()` in `JniBridge.kt` gets called correctly with an integer.

But here's what I don't get: If I change my callback to send a String it doesn't work. If I change it like this:

```
// in JniBridge.kt
 fun stringCallback(value: String) {
        someListener?.invoke(value)
    }
```

```
// in Callback.cpp

//getting the method
id = g_env->GetMethodID(target, "stringCallback", "(Ljava/lang/String)V");

//making the call
g_env->CallVoidMethod(g_object, id, (jstring) stringValue);
```

Now my app crashes with this error:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetStringUTFChars called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/my/app/common/jni/JniBridge;.stringCallback(Ljava/lang/String)V"
```

The same happens if I try calling a `void` method (like this: `id = g_env->GetMethodID(target, "voidCallback", "(V)V");`or calling one that takes two integers (like this: `id = g_env->GetMethodID(target, "twoIntegerCallback", "(I;I)V");`, of course with having the corresponding methods in `JniBridge.kt` in place.

**Why does this happen and how can I fix it?**

Note: For clarity I have omitted all parts of my code that I believe are not related to the problem, if something crucial is missing, please let me know and I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon in the method signature that you pass to `GetMethodID`.

It should be:

```
id = g_env->GetMethodID(target, "stringCallback", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
```

Note the semi-colon after `Ljava/lang/String`.

See the part about Type Signatures in [Oracle's JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp276).

---

Regarding your other variations:

A Java `void function()` would have the signature `()V`.
A Java `void function(int i, int j)` would have the signature `(II)V`.

---

As a side note, you really ought to verify the return value and check for exceptions after every JNI call.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this is all correct, and the link points exactly to the right document. Somehow I've put a different syntax mistake into each attempt. And I might just not know enough about this, but to the untrained eye the type signatures syntax looks kind of inconsistent with its use of semicolons for full qualified classes but no separation at all for primitives, especially in combination this ir really hard to read.
And thanks for the side note - I will take care of that!

Comment: One additional note though: `g_env->CallVoidMethod(g_object, id, (jstring) stringValue);`doesn't work as I found out , building the correct string for the JNI to hand it over in this call needs to be done like this: `g_env->CallVoidMethod(g_object, id, g_env->CallVoidMethod(g_object, id,  g_env->NewStringUTF(mFileName));`

Comment: If you're doing this on a purely native thread, then you should assign the value returned by `NewStringUTF` to a variable so that you call `DeleteLocalRef` when you no longer need the Java string. Otherwise you might end up overflowing your local reference table (unless you're constantly attaching and detaching the native thread).